# How to optimize the following fragment of C++ code - zero crossings in a volume

Tags: c++, computer-vision

I am struggling to optimize the following fragment of code. The function is being called for every voxel in a 320x320x320 volume where each voxel is a 16bit grayscale value. The volume is stored as a series of planes (cross sections) and each plane is a contiguous 1D array, hence for example the position of a voxel below current voxel becomes currentPosition + pixelsPerRow and position to the left of it becomes currentPosition - 1.

The function checks for both zero crossings in the volume and if the absolute value of current and neighboring voxel is above certain threshold. This is a neccessary part of Marr-Hildreth edge detector.

currentPosition is the current voxel and relativePosition can be either the current voxel too (in that case zero crossings are checked in 8 directions around it in the same plane) or it can be voxel directly above or directly below it. This way, for every voxel, 27 checks are performed which covers all the possible directions in 3D.

Perhaps it is possible to rearrange the function in such the way that its execution will be faster. I already tried to arrange the order of checks in such the way that branch prediction has a slightly better chance to kick in, but maybe it's possible to speed it up even more. For now it takes 50% processing time of a much larger application so it begs for some optimizations.

```
 bool zeroCrossing(int16_t* currentPosition, int16_t* relativePosition, int pixelsPerRow, int threshold)
        {
            return *currentPosition * *(relativePosition - pixelsPerRow - 1) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition - pixelsPerRow - 1)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition - pixelsPerRow) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition - pixelsPerRow)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition - pixelsPerRow + 1) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition - pixelsPerRow + 1)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition - 1) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition - 1)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition + 1) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition + 1)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition + pixelsPerRow - 1) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition + pixelsPerRow - 1)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition + pixelsPerRow) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition + pixelsPerRow)) > threshold
                || *currentPosition * *(relativePosition + pixelsPerRow + 1) < 0 && abs(*currentPosition + *(relativePosition + pixelsPerRow + 1)) > threshold;
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps introducing some temporary variables with descriptive names could help you get more feedback here. Also, you did compile your application with compiler optimizations enabled, right?

Comment: Well you make some computations twice or more. If you factor them, you should be able to optimize your function a bit. E:g: `*currentPosition * *(relativePosition - pixelsPerRow - 1) < 0` is tested twice, and `*currentPosition * *(relativePosition + pixelsPerRow)` computed many times

Comment: @MaartenBamelis yes, compiled with VS 2015 C++ 14 with optimizations on.

Comment: @papagaga: So? You can do manual Common Subexpression Elimination, or rely on the compiler for that.

Comment: @MSalters: yes but when you're not satisfied with the result you have to try and do the optimization by yourself, don't you?

Comment: @papagaga I already tried to do this manually and it was actually working slightly slower. It doesn't seem to help. I think going for AVX would be the best option if possible, but I don't know ASM good enough to do it myself :( I don't even know where I could learn that.

Comment: @MaxWalczak: It starts with telling VS2015 that _it_ may use AVX2. see C/C++ properties, Code Generation tab, `/arch:AVX2`.

Comment: I think rewriting to use AVX2 is a typical case of too early optimization... You need to remove redundancy first. See my answer below. Once the logic is right, go ahead and optimize you code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut instinct is that this code lends itself well to parallelization. Either use AVX(2), or offload this to a GPU. That would take it outside the realm of C++, but that is a reasonable thing to do for the core function of a program.

I'm assuming you already use threads to parallelize the operation, because that is pretty trivial. Note that with AVX you'd still need threads; each CPU core has it's own AVX unit.

Comment: I used AVX using Agner's Vector lib and I gained 2x speedup. Everything is now performed as vector sums, vector multiplies and compares. The problem is solved. Thank you for the good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a zero crossing, it will happen in between two neighboring pixels. When running through the volume, you need to check each pair of neighbors only once. If you apply your function to each pixel, you'll check each pair twice. (I use the term pixel for the elements of a 3D image too, I don't like the term voxel a whole lot).

Also, you check pairs of pixels that share an edge or a vertex, you only need to check those that share a face. If there is a zero crossing between pixels `a` and `d` in the figure below, there must be one between `a` and `b` or between `a` and `c`.

```
a   b
c   d
```

Thus, for each pixel, you only need to check three neighbors, not 27. This would reduce your execution time to 1/9.

However, this does not exactly account for your magnitude check, the difference between `a` and `d` could be larger than that between either of its other two neighbors. However, I don't think this is important.

On that note, your magnitude check is wrong:  if `a` and `b` differ in sign and are both very large (an important zero crossing), then `abs(a + b)` could be 0, and you wouldn't count it. You probably want to take the difference!

Comment: And I add this as a comment because it doesn't directly answer your question, but are you sure you want to detect zero crossings? It's a nice theoretical concept, but there's a reason it's not used in practice... why not look for local maxima in the gradient magnitude, as Canny does? I haven't seen it applied in 3D, but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. Shoot, now I want to go and try that out...

Comment: It is because the specific application relies on Marr-Hildreth on purpose - what we want are not exactly edges - we want large, thick, edge-like blobs.